# Cypher: Multiple independent queries in one call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

in my Neo4j 2.0 server database I have a forest, i.e. a set of trees. One of my use cases is to get the child nodes of an arbitrary subset of tree nodes.

For instance, I have the root nodes

```
root1 root2 root3 root4
```

and now I want the child nodes of `root1` and `root4`. **And I need to know which children belong to which root**. Each query individually is a simple MATCH Cypher query. But for the sake of performance I would like to keep the amount of database calls low since I use the Neo4j server. Thus I am thinking about a way to tell Cypher "give me the child terms of root1 and root4 and tell me which node belongs to which root in the result". That is, I think of a kind of map. Or a collection of result sets where the first element is the child nodes of the first root, the second element the child nodes of the second root etc.

Is there a way to do this in Cypher or will I have to fall back to a server plugin here?

Thank you and best regards!

**Edit:**

To clarify: My main concern is that I need to know which children belong to which root. As an example, consider the small graph generated by this command:

```
create (r1:ROOT {name:"root1"}),
(r2:ROOT {name:"root2"}),
(c11:CHILD {name:"child1_1"}),
(c12:CHILD {name:"child1_2"}),
(c13:CHILD {name:"child1_3"}),
(c21:CHILD {name:"child2_1"}),
(c22:CHILD {name:"child2_2"}),
(c23:CHILD {name:"child2_3"}),
(r1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c11),
(r1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c12),
(r1)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c13),
(r2)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c21),
(r2)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c22),
(r2)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c23)
```

Here, we get `root1` and `root2` with three children, respectively.

To get the children of `root1` I would issue the following query:

```
MATCH (r:ROOT)-[:HAS_CHILD]->c where r.name='root1' RETURN collect(c)
```

Now I know the children of root `root1`.
The question is: How would a query look like that queries the children of `root1` AND `root2` where the result would show the association of which child belongs to which root. Because clearly the query

```
MATCH (r:ROOT)-[:HAS_CHILD]->c where r.name='root1' OR r.name='root2' RETURN collect(c.id)
```

would give me the children of both roots. But now I would not know which root had which children. So what can I do?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, what does the query for a single tree look like? If you look up the single root by property value you can probably just modify it to look up many roots by a collection of values.

Comment: Yeah, give us more details and we can build you a query.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Please accept my apologies for the not quite elaborated issue description, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give us more details but a query like this (adjusting properties and relationships), should work as you want:

```
MATCH (child) <-[:HAS_CHILD]- (root:ROOT)
WHERE root.name IN ['root1','root4']
RETURN child, root
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I edited my post and hope now there are sufficient information. Regarding your proposed query: Now I would have all children but I would not which child belonged to which root.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the root of the child in return

Comment: Oh my, this was easy. Thank you very much and I nearly feel I had to apologise for this obviously weak question. In the end, I will probably go with MATCH (r:ROOT)-[:HAS_CHILD]->c WHERE r.name='root1' OR r.name='root2' return collect(c),r;  because then I even have the children grouped by the respective root node. Thanks again!